# Trying output previously input strings two in a row in TASM

Tags: assembly, input, output, tasm

Well, title says it all: if for example I input "a", then I get this "antered string: a" (sic!). I do something wrong and I can not figure out what is happening.

```
model tiny
.code
org     0100h
start:
  mov     ax,cs           ;set data seg == code seg
  mov     ds,ax 

  mov dx,offset tm
  mov ah,0ah
  int 21h
  mov dx,offset testm
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h
  mov dx,offset tm
  add dx,2h
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h
  mov dx,offset tm
  add dx,2h
  mov ah,09h
  int 21h
  ret

tm  db 255,255,255 dup("$")
testm   db "Entered string: $"

End start
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Int 21h/0Ah`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) stores the pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as `0Dh`. This is for [`Int 21h/09h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) a "carriage return" and only a "carriage return". You need an additional "line feed". You can add the line feed (`10h`) to the end of the `tm` string or add a further [`Int 21h/09`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) procedure which points to a string only containing the two line feed characters and a terminating `$` (`crlf db 0Dh, 0Ah, "$"`).

Instead of adding a line feed you can change the `0Dh` in `tm` to '$' to get the "raw" string:

```
MODEL tiny
.CODE
.386                                    ; for `movzx`
ORG 0100h

start:
    mov dx, offset tm
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset crlf                 ; Carriage Return & Line Feed & '$'
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    movzx di, byte ptr [tm + 1]         ; Length of string w/o the last 0Dh
    add di, OFFSET tm + 2               ; Plus start offset of string -> DI points to 0Dh
    mov byte ptr [di], '$'              ; Change 0Dh to '$'

    mov dx,offset testm
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset tm
    add dx,2h
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset tm
    add dx,2h
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    ret

tm      db 255,255,255 dup("$")
testm   db "Entered string: $"
crlf    db 0Dh, 0Ah, "$"

END start
```

An elegant method is to utilize the WriteFile function [`Int21h/40h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2791.htm):

```
model tiny
.code
org     0100h

start:
    mov dx, offset tm
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset crlf
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset testm
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset tm + 2
    xor ch, ch
    mov cl, tm + 1              ; Length of tm = number of bytes to write
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1                   ; Handle 1: StdOut
    int 21h                     ; BX, CX & DX not changed

    mov ah, 40h                 ; Once more.
    mov bx, 1
    int 21h

    ret

tm      db 255,255,255 dup("$")
testm   db "Entered string: $"
crlf    db 0Dh, 0Ah, "$"

End start
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but if I want to just add space in between tm and tm but not a new line? I asume I need to modify crlf db 0Dh, 0Ah, "$" somehow

Comment: @AbFi: Look at my upgraded answer.